# Is a function recursive if it calls itself TRIVIALLY

Tags: c, recursion

I was asked to write a recursive code to print an array. A friend showed me this code:

```
include <stdio.h>
int i=0;

void print(int A[], int n)
{
    if(i<n)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        i++;
        print(A, n);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[3]={3, 5, 2};
    print(A, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Technically, it is recursive because the function calls itself, but I think *trivially* !! It does not break the problem into smaller problems or anything like that. So, it felt like *cheating*. Faking as if it is recursion.

Can the function in this code be consider recursive? Is this a fine way to use recursion?

What about in this form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int A[], int n, int i)
{
    if(i<n)
    {
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
        print(A, n, i+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[3]={3, 5, 2}, i=0;
    print(A, 3, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's *all* that's required. A function doesn't have to be non-trivial, or be useful, or even *work* to be recursive. It just has to call itself.

Comment: Yes, a function is recursive, when it calls itself.

Comment: The problem you stated will not benefit from recursion. Printing array is a naturally linear problem. So this code is close enough to the ideal solution. But you can, for example, make a very slight change in it to print the array backwards. That's fun.

Comment: It does break the problem to a smaller one - the index is closer to the end each call.

Comment: Oooh, that static variable is ugly, though. Forget trying to call this function later on something else.

Comment: Yeah.. you could utilize `n` in a better way...

Comment: if you mean 'is this a good use of recursion?' then the answer is no. This code is more obscure than its simple non recursive cousin. And it introduces potential bug with its static variable (which is there to disguise the recursion)

Comment: The edit did not make it any better.

Comment: Instead of making your code simple - this recursion is a overhead.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. But got rid of the static int, didn't it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Tail recursion is recursion.  In some style guides for some programming languages, tail recursion is the recommended way to visit all of the members of a list.

Comment: @Truth-seek , no it moved the static to a different scope, which is even worse

Comment: @jameslarge In *functional* languages. Yes. Because they don't have loops :)

Comment: Note that the discussion here is all about direct recursion. You can also have indirectly recursive functions where function A calls function B and function B calls function A.  This is less common but perfectly permissible, and still recursive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a recursive function, since it calls itself.

Additionally, the function does break the problem to smaller problems - in this case, precisely one smaller problem: printing the array starting from index `i+1` instead from index `i`. Since the bound is greater than `i`, the problem is smaller.

In other words, the recursion is *well founded*: the value of `n-i` is decreasing at each call, and the edge case of `n-i==0` is handled trivially, not recursively.

Answer (score 5):

> Can the function in this code be consider recursive?

Yes, recursion occurs when the function can call itself, either directly *or* indirectly.

> Is this a fine way to use recursion?

No.  Although some compilers may optimize the code, code risks incurring `n` levels of recursion and causing [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

A better alternative is to *halve* the problem.  This breaks the problem in 2 at each step.

```
void print(int A[], int n, int i) {
  if (i<n) {
    A += i; n -= i;  // zero offset A and n

    int mid = n/2;
    print(A, mid, 0);              // print left side of A
    printf("%d ", A[mid]);         // print middle of A
    int right = n - mid - 1; 
    print(A + mid + 1, right, 0);  // print right side of A
  }
}
```

If `n` was 1000, the above could incur a recursion depth of log2(1000) or about 10 instead of 1000.  An unbounded `n` is a reason  recursion can be abused.  Insure that the recursion depth is not excessive.

---

Notice that parameter `i` is not really needed.

```
void printA(int A[], size_t n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    size_t mid = n/2;
    printA(A, mid);              // print left side of A
    printf("%d ", A[mid]);       // print middle of A
    size_t right = n - mid - 1; 
    printA(A + mid + 1, right);  // print right side of A
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the number of lines in a function, it is recursive if it calls itself.

```
void print(int A[], int n) {
   if(n == 0) 
      printf("%d", *A);
   print(++A, --n);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `static` variable you can pass the `starting` element address and `last` elements address of the array and do the same task.

```
void print(int *A_start, int *A_end) {
        if(A_start < A_end) { /* call the function itself until A_start not reaches A_end */
                printf("%d ", *A_start);
                A_start++;
                print(A_start,A_end);
        }
}

int main() {
        int A[3]={3, 5, 2};
        int ele = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
        print(A,A+ele);
        return 0;
}
```